# How to make physical simulation of unmixable fluids (like oil and water) in any container

Tags: fluid-simulation

I wish to make an animation of pouring water over oil or vice versa. In physical simulation, how do I make oil thicker than water and make both liquids behave realistically when stirred and left to settle?

Comment: Have a look at the [molecular addon](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r3-PSEijh_I)

Comment: Thanks, @sambler. I have looked at few videos on molecular addon. Thanks for mentioning the addon.

Answer (score 2):

The fluid simulation engine that ships with Blender isn't capable of mixing two fluids.

They would require two separate domains, with different parameters, being baked at the same time and reading the other domain's status frame-by-frame as input for themselves. Unfortunately, this kind of "simultaneous bake" isn't possible.

Comment: That is useful to know and I'll keep that in mind. Thanks.